# How to use two separate colours for two lines in a single 'Plot' within the 'With' command?

Tags: plotting, scoping, style

'''With[{k = {1, 10}}, Plot[k*x^2, {x, 0, 1}]]'''

> I want to use **two separate colours** for two k values. How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap the first argument of `Plot` with [`Evaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html)

```
With[{k = {1, 10}}, Plot[Evaluate[k*x^2], {x, 0, 1}]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, add the option [`Evaluated -> True`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluated.html):

```
With[{k = {1, 10}}, Plot[k*x^2, {x, 0, 1}, Evaluated -> True]]
```

> same picture

Comment: @ChowdhuryAminulIslam, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: @kgir, I can further use 'PlotStyle' within the command to customise the colours.

Comment: yes, you can use, for example, `PlotStyle-> {Red, Green}` or `PlotStyle->{Directive[Thick, Dashed, Orange],Directive[Dotted, Purple]}` etc.